# JS Events not firing in browsers on iPhone or on Safari on Mac

Tags: javascript, ios, events

I've had a look at various forums, including on Stack Overflow, and have even asked the cursed AI for help. My code runs fine on my PC and android phone but not on the browsers in the title. I have tried using touchstart instead of touchmove, tried removing/altering "{passive : true}", even removing the entirety of my code and keeping only the "onLightPress" function and having it do the following: `logo.innerHTML="hi"` and nothing works (it continued to function in other browsers on other devices).

What is going wrong? My variables are correctly grabbing the elements from my HTML as it functions in other browsers. I've attached code that includes a darkmode function just as an example, as even just running this one function has the same problem:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    //REQUIRED VARIABLES
    var lightmode = 0;
    const tiles = document.querySelector('.tiles');
    const shuffled = document.querySelector('.shuffled');
    const lightbulb = document.querySelector('#lightbulb');
    let heading = document.querySelector('.heading');
    let logo = document.querySelector('.logo');
    let box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    let hidden = document.querySelectorAll('.hiddenletters');
    let body = document.querySelector('.body');
    let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    let revealed = document.querySelector('.revealed');
    let toptimes = document.querySelector('.toptimes');
    let ranking = document.querySelectorAll('.ranking');
    let donate = document.querySelector('.donate');
    counttoday.classList.toggle('logodark');

    //LIGHTBULB FUNCTIONALITY
    lightbulb.addEventListener('touchmove', onLightPress, { passive: true });
    lightbulb.addEventListener('click', onLightPress, { passive: true });
    
    function onLightPress() {
        heading.classList.toggle('headingdark');
        logo.classList.toggle('logodark');
        tiles.classList.toggle('tilesdark');
        Array.from(box).forEach((box) => box.classList.toggle('boxdark'));
        Array.from(shuffled).forEach((shuffled) => shuffled.classList.toggle('shuffleddark'));
        Array.from(hidden).forEach((hidden) => hidden.classList.toggle('hiddenlettersdark'));
        body.classList.toggle('bodydark');
        menu.classList.toggle('menudark');
        revealed.classList.toggle('logodark');
        toptimes.classList.toggle('logodark');
        counttoday.classList.toggle('logodark');
        donate.classList.toggle('logodark');
        lightmode++;
        
        if (lightmode % 2 != 0) {
            Array.from(ranking).forEach((ranking) => ranking.setAttribute('id', 'darktext'));
        } else {
            Array.from(ranking).forEach((ranking) => ranking.removeAttribute('id', 'darktext'));
        }
    }
})
```

(Excuse my inability to toggle ranking lmao)

If anyone could help with this, I'd massively appreciate it as I've been stuck for days even when trying recommendations from other Stack Overflow posts! TIA

Comment: So is the function being called?

Comment: @epascarello On other devices yes, I unfortunately can't tell on my iPhone as I don't have a Mac to connect it to to look at the Safari console, if you have access to one and are able to check that'd be a great help, i've added a console log to the lightbulb that should indicate its firing: https://www.dailyminutegram.com

Comment: This doesn't fix your problem, however there are third party console tools that work on mobile. I have had similar problems where only mobile devices were having problems and I needed a console. Here is one https://github.com/liriliri/eruda

Comment: Use an alert... develop like we did in the 90's

Comment: @epascarello guessing it's not firing then as I had tried that previously, any ideas as to why?